# Subset function not removing NAs

Tags: r, subset, na

I have a data frame like this:

```
df

Date     Player Injured
1/2/2012      A      No
1/3/2012      B     Yes
1/4/2012      C      No
1/5/2012      B      NA
1/5/2012      A      No
1/7/2012      B     Yes
1/8/2012      A      No
1/3/2012      B     Yes
1/2/2012      D      No
1/3/2012      F      NA
```

I am trying to use subset function to select players that injury info is NA:

```
x <- subset(df, injured!="NA")
```

x data frame is not populating. It seems very straightforward. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: do you mean "select players that injury info is NOT `NA`"?  If so, then modify @Alan's answer below to use `!is.na(Injured)` ...  PS -- it's better to state **explicitly** what's not working (although in this case we can guess pretty well) than to just say "it's not working"

Comment: why does != not work, if == does work?  I would expect != to give me the opposite of ==.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `x<-subset(df, is.na(Injured))` .